# IntelliJ javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, io

I simply want to load an Image.

In an older Program it works. The only difference is, that the old one uses directories and this one uses packages. Actually I can't even create a directory.

Thats the Stacktrace:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at com.company.ImageLoader.loadImage(ImageLoader.java:17)
    at com.company.Window.Window.<init>(Window.java:30)
    at com.company.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:21)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

[image]

[image]

```
public class Window
{
    private JFrame myFrame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel mainLabel;
    private ImageLoader myImageLoader = new ImageLoader();

    public Window(Boolean defaultLaFDeco, String title, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(defaultLaFDeco);
        myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setTitle(title);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainLabel = new JLabel();
        mainPanel.add(mainLabel);
        myFrame.add(mainPanel);
        myFrame.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

        File file = new File("Res/cat/0.jpg");
        BufferedImage img = myImageLoader.loadImage(file);
    }
}

public class ImageLoader
{
    private BufferedImage image = null;

    public BufferedImage loadImage(File file)
    {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't create a directory in package tree. Try ``new File("../Res/cat/0.jpg");``

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that the image was basically in src directory.